# c++ result of sum of doubles is wrong

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

```
bool func(double &u, double &v){
    .
    .
    .
    if((u+v) <= 1.0)
        return false;
    cout <<"u:  " << u << "  v:  " << v << endl;
    return true;
}
```

I have a function like this. 
Output is:

```
u: 0.914812  v:  0.0851877
```

Their sum is: **0.9999997**. However the program does not go in the if statement. It returns true. Why?

Comment: could you send link of that question?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/96oQ8D)

Comment: Values shown are rounded, there are probably several more digits which brings sum over 1

Comment: This question isn't a dup of the referenced question. Just look at the very top of that one. It's about the testing-for-equality fallacy. Then there's lots of discussion of the philosophy of floating point numbers. This question could be about precision of printing even with a numeric system which wasn't subject to the flakiness of floats. Suppose the question was "why is 1KB + 1 KB > 3KB?" and we discovered the questioner was dividing integers by 1024 for printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 0.914812499999999 and 0.0851877499999999. Perhaps those numbers aren't what you think they are. Print them with more precision